# Blade templating: Can unprocessed tags have php echo inside?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to loop through an array and put the `$key` inside of an unprocessed Blade tag, e.g.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (array_keys($array) as $key)
            <tr>
                <th>
                    {{ $key }}
                </th>
                <td>

                    <!-- THIS -->
                    @{{ model.{{ $key }}  }}

                    <!-- OR THIS -->
                    @{{ model.<?= $key ?> }}

                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is for later use with AngularJS. Is there any way to do this short of having to hard-code all of these `$key`s?

Comment: what do you mean by unprocessed blade tag? do you want to not show the key value but keep it as a variable?

Comment: When you put `@{{ stuff }}` into a blade template, it will end up `{{ stuff }}` once the template is processed and stored as plain PHP. Say `$key = 'id'`, I would like `@{{ model.<?= $key ?> }}` to be stored as `{{ model.id }}` once everything is said and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom blade directive , i made this , it will serve your purpose , add this in your AppServiceProvider class

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('ng', function($var) {
            return "<?php echo \"@{{ model.\" ?><?php echo with{$var} ?> <?php echo \"}}\" ?> ";
        });
    }
```

now you can use it in your blade view like this

```
@ng($key)
```

which will render as

```
{{ model.id }}
```

this can also be done like these which is not good looking

```
<?php echo '{{ model.' . $key . ' }}'; ?>
```

Comment: You could clean it up like: `<?php echo '{{ model.' . $product->name . ' }}'; ?>`